# Magento 2.3 Header Skewed

Tags: magento2, css, header

I have modified the header in my Magento2 site and it appears skewed to the right. I have checked the CSS of the div and the subsequent elements - logo, search and cart and cannot find a fix. Attached is a screen shot and the living site can be seen here: shorturl.at/nFJMT

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: There could be any number of reasons for this, it's hard to tell without having a link to the site or the code. A guess would be a max-width or flexbox related issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to Magento, it's a general CSS issue. Also, more details are needed as it's very unlikely this can be fixed without either a link to the site or the used CSS.

Comment: @BenCrook The link is in the original post: shorturl.at/nFJMT

Comment: The link doesn't work, it just loads a URL shortener site with an ad and a request for notifications.

Comment: Try shorturl.at/hpCF2

Comment: Add this code in css 

.header.content>* {
    flex: auto !important;
}

Comment: @RanjeetKumar It still looks skewed after adding and clearing the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS:

```
.header.content .minicart-wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.header.content .logo {
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

**OR**

Remove `flex: none!important` from `.header.content>*`

[image]

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you.